# Spring batch update db status after rollback due to exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-transactions

In Spring batch Writer I'm updating the db row status from 0 to 1. If any exception occurs update to 2.
However due to @transaction rollback I'm unable to update the status to 2.

(I'm throwing exception to trigger the rollback)

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void write(List<? extends TestEntity> enityList) throws Exception {
    
    for(TestEntity testEntity : enityList) {
        try {
            
        
            testEntity.setStatus(2);
            testRepository.save(testEntity);
            testRepository.flush();
            
            testMethod(testEntity); (which throws exception)
        
        }catch (Exception exception) {              
            testEntity.setStatus(2);
            testRepository.save(testEntity);
        }
        
    }
}   



@Transactional
public void testMethod(TestEntity testEntity) throws Exception {

    try{

    //Some service call
    //...
    
    } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("error", e);
            throw new Exception("exp");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your question "How do I store data despite the transaction being rolled back?"

Comment: You will need a separate transaction to update the status. Can you show the code of the Writer, please

Comment: I tried by commenting the @Transaction of write(). Still not working

Comment: @dube yeah that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Methods that have the `@Transactional` will rollback the transaction when they throw an exception. So if an exception is an expected and okay-ish flow of your code, you shouldn't throw an exception and return some kind of result object or status code instead.

```
@Transactional
public void testMethodThatIsAllowedToFail(TestEntity testEntity) {
    try{
        //Some service call
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return Status.FAILURE; // enum you have to create
    }
    return Status.SUCCESS;
}

// spring batch writer
public void write(List<? extends TestEntity> enityList) throws Exception {
    [...]
    Status result = testMethod(testEntity); (which throws exception);
    if (result != Status.SUCCESS) {
        // do something with it
    }
    [...]
}
```

you could also play around with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` but you would have to think hard whether having an extra transaction is desireable.